# Add specific form to item inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  <div>{{post.description}}</div>
  <ul *ngFor="let comment of post.comments">
    <li>
      {{comment.description}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <textarea placeholder="leave your comments here"></textarea>
    <button (click)="addComment(post)">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Considering it will contains a lot of posts on the page, how can I add dynamically a new comment to the specific post I am writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to make a post component containing also a struktur (like array) holding your comments. Then apply *ngFor with your new component.

Maybe something like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9tkry

It ended like:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let post of posts">
   <app-post [post]="post"></app-post>
 </ng-container>
```

And on `app-post`:

```
<p>
  {{post.text}}
</p>
<ul *ngFor="let comment of post.comments">
  <li>{{comment}}</li>
</ul>
<textarea [(ngModel)]="newComment"></textarea>
<button (click)="addComment()">Add comment</button>
```

Comment: Your answer works correctly and is semantically excellent! Could you just include your link to edit Stackblitz in your reply? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

consider adding following function signature, to pass both related post **and** new comment:

```
<textarea placeholder="leave your comments here" #commentText></textarea>
<button (click)="addComment(post, commentText)">Save</button>
```

Then, assuming that comments are part of post model, just append new comment to already existing:

```
addComment(post: any, newComment: HTMLInputElement){
   post.comments.push(newComment.value);
}
```

Comment: @PatrickLima Glad I could help. Hovewer keep in mind, that using template variables (i.e. those with #) is considered rather a poor practice. If you work with forms a lot of, please consider using template driven forms with ngModel (as described by Sajeetharan) or even better, reactive forms to separate business logic from view entirely. Template variables shall be used as last resort or when deadline is coming :)

Comment: I have transferred the correct answer to J. Knabenschuh's comment because it rightly uses a semantic standard and good practice. Thanks again for your help, even though it was not the final answer, it helped me to understand the problem very well and to learn that template variables are not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

since you are passing the post to the addComment method, you should be able to push to the same comments array.

```
addComment(post:any){
   post.comments.push(comment);
}
```

and add ngModel to your template,

```
<textarea placeholder="leave your comments here" [(ngModel)]='comment'
```

Comment: But on the `<textarea>` the `[(ngModel)]='comment'` reference is outside the comments `*ngFor`

Comment: yeah this is just an idea, you can follow thomas's answer